# Possibility to search in one or more columns of the same table SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have a splint where several products are displayed. On the left side are several options so that the person can make filters in the list of products.

I am trying to create a form if the variable has value it will be assembled in parts.

This is my code:

```
if (!empty($_GET) && (!empty($_GET['search']))) {
    $where = "WHERE"; 
}else{
    $url_atual = "";
}

if (isset($_GET['search']) && ($_GET['search'] != "")) {
    $serch = "titulo LIKE '%".$_GET['search']."%' ";
}else{
    $serch = "";
}

if (isset($_GET['cat']) && ($_GET['cat'] != "")) {
    $cat = "AND categoria = ".$_GET['cat']." ";
}else{
    $cat = "";
}

if (isset($_GET['cat_sub']) && ($_GET['cat_sub'] != "")) {
    $cat_sub = "AND subcategoria IN ('".$_GET['cat_sub']."')";
}else{
    $cat_sub = "";
}

if (isset($_GET['fpag']) && ($_GET['fpag'] != "all")) {
    $fpag = "AND fixoHora = '".$_GET['fpag']."' ";
}else{
    $fpag = "";
}


$projetos = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM projetos {$where} {$serch} {$cat} {$cat_sub} {$fpag} LIMIT {$inicio},{$itens_por_pagina}");
```

### Problem

As I am using `AND`, at the beginning of the variables, if any variable is not initialized, such as `search`, of the error, because it would start like this:

```
SELECT * FROM projetos AND cat = 1
```

Is there a better way to do these searches?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developing dynamic queries is a tricky thing because you have to account for every possible variation and eventuality. Because of this, the less options you have, the better. In this case, you have 4. The way I solved this was to detail every outcome. I am not saying this is perfect, and someone might come along with a better more concise approach, but this is how I would do it:

### 1. map out your logic with pseudocode

Start with basic query

Is there a search term? 
**yes**: add 'like'
**No**: blank

Is there a category and a search? 
**Yes**: add 'AND category'
**No**: is there a category?
**Yes**: add 'category'.
**No**: blank

Is there a category and a subcategory OR a search and a subcategory?
**Yes**: add 'AND subcategory'
**No**: is there a subcategory?
**Yes**: add 'subcategory'
**No**: blank

Is there a Category OR a subcategory OR a Search 
**yes**: if there is an fpag, add 'AND fpag'
**no**: is there an fpag
**Yes**: add 'fpag'
**No**: blank

### 2. translate to if and else statements and append the original query

```
//Basic query
if (!empty($_GET)) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM projetos WHERE "; 
    }
else{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM projetos";
}

//is there a search term?
if (isset($_GET['search']) && ($_GET['search'] != "")) {
    $query .= "titulo LIKE '%".$_GET['search']."%' ";
    }
else{
    $query .= "";
}

//is there a category and a search?
if (isset($_GET['cat']) && (isset($_GET['search']))) {
    $query .= "AND categoria = ".$_GET['cat']." ";
    }
else{
    if (isset($_GET['cat'])){
        $query .= "categoria = ".$_GET['cat']." ";
        }
    else{
         $query .= "";
        }
}

//is there a Category and a subcategory OR a search and a Subcategory?is there a Category and a subcategory OR a search and a Subcategory?
if (isset($_GET['cat']) && isset($_GET['cat_sub']) || isset($_GET['search']) && isset($_GET['cat_sub'])){
         $query .= "AND subcategoria IN ('".$_GET['cat_sub']."') ";
    }
else{
    if(isset($_GET['cat_sub'])){
        $query .= "subcategoria IN ('".$_GET['cat_sub']."') ";
        }
        else{
            $query .= "";
        }
    }

//is there a Category OR a subcategory OR a Search  
if(isset($_GET['cat']) || isset($_GET['search']) || isset($_GET['cat_sub'])){
    if(isset($_GET['fpag'])){
            $query .= "AND fixoHora = '".$_GET['fpag']."' ";
        }
        else{
            $query .= "";
        }
    }
else{
    if(isset($_GET['fpag'])){
            $query .= "fixoHora = '".$_GET['fpag']."' ";
        }
    else{
            $query .= "";
        }
    }
$projetos = $conn->query($query . "LIMIT  {$inicio},{$itens_por_pagina}");
```

I ran a quick check on the code above and it seemed to work. It's possible to amend the above code to make sure the $_GET values are not blank but that can be done in validation before the page is loaded.

I hope this helps.